# Is it known the $S_n$-module structures of free anti-commutative algebra

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, free-modules, representation-of-algebras

I recently started studiyng representation theory, especially I am interested in $S_n$-module structures of free algebras over some variety. I know that the $S_n$-module structures are known for some algebras, like, free Novikov, free Lie, free bicommutative and free commutative algebras. But I have found no information about free anti-commutative algebras. Is it known the $S_n$-module structures for free anti-commutative algebras? If yes, can someone share with this reference?

Comment: Hyphens, not minus signs.